# SQL to Entity Framework query for distinct instances

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4

I need to translate the following query from SQL into an Entity Framework query.  Can anyone please help.

```
                var query3 = string.Format(@"
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        Boxes.BoxName,
                        Employees.EmployeeNumber,
                        Boxes.Port,
                        Boxes.SerialNumber
                    FROM
                        Eventlog

                        INNER JOIN Boxes 
                            ON Eventlog.SerialNumber = Boxes.SerialNumber

                        INNER JOIN Employees 
                            ON Eventlog.EmployeeId = Employees.EmployeeId

                    WHERE
                        ActionId = {4}
                        AND Boxes.Deactivated = 0
                        AND ( ('*' = '{0}')
                            OR (Boxes.SerialNumber = '{0}') )
                        AND ( (-1 = {1})
                            OR (Employees.EmployeeId = '{1}') )
                        AND EventTime >= '{2}'
                        AND EventTime <= '{3}'
                    ", boxFilter3, ReportEmployeeIdFilter, ReportStartDate, ReportEndDate, actionFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var query = (from log in context.Eventlog
             join box in context.Boxes 
                on log.SerialNumber equals box.SerialNumber
             join employee in context.Employees 
                on log.EmployeeId equals employee.EmployeeId
             where log.ActionId == actionFilter 
             && box.Deactivated == 0
             && (boxFilter3 == "*" || box.SerialNumber == boxFilter3)
             && (ReportEmployeeIdFilter == -1 || employee.EmployeeId == ReportEmployeeIdFilter)
             && log.EventTime >= ReportStartDate
             && log.EventTime <= ReportEndDate
             select new
             {
                box.BoxName,
                employee.EmployeeNumber,
                box.Port,
                box.SerialNumber
             })
             .Distinct();
```

Comment: What if I need to return the whole object rather than the individual fields?  I forgot to add that change.

Comment: @PrestonPhillips: Just change the `select` part of the query. For example, `select new { box, employee, log }`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure I see how that will create only the distinct elements though.

Comment: @PrestonPhillips: Sorry, I missed off the call to `Distinct`. It's not supported in the query syntax, so you have to call it as an extension method. It probably won't have much effect if you're returning the entire object, though.

Comment: The objects are liable to be different even if the values they contain are the same.    But this would work for a flattened object.